# NULL POINTER error when using ObjectLoad(ObjectSave())

Tags: coldfusion, nullpointerexception, coldfusion-9, cfc, railo

**Update**  this has been filed as a bug in ColdFusion, https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3546237

I've been having a problem with CF9 and NULL POINTER errors that do not appear to be an issue within Railo.  I created a simple CFC and associated mxunit unit test to confirm this with.

On Railo (4.0.4) both unit tests pass.  On Coldfusion (9.0.1), the unit test getMetaDataBeforeMethodInvocation fails with NULL POINTER error on the GetMetaData call.

At present I can only surmise that CF9 does not have access to the full metadata following ObjectLoad until a method within that component is called.  Is anyone able to shed more light on this problem, and/or offer a better solution than to ensure that a method within the object is called prior to doing getMetaData?

Here is the CFC

```
// NullError.cfc
component {
    public NullError function init() {
        variables.uuid = CreateUUID();
        return this;
    }
    public string function getUUID() {
        return uuid;
    }
}
```

and associated unit test

```
// NullErrorTest.cfc
component extends='mxunit.framework.TestCase' {
    private any function setupTheTests() {
        var o = new NullError();
        debug(o.getUUID());
        // Dump meta data
        debug(GetMetaData(o));
        // Save and load it, and return
        return ObjectLoad(ObjectSave(o));
    }

    public void function getMetaDataBeforeMethodInvocation() {
        var o = setupTheTests();
        // Get meta data, and then get uuid, expecting this to ERROR (NULL POINTER)
        debug(GetMetaData(o)); // CF FAILS HERE, RAILO DOES NOT
        debug(o.getUUID());
    }

    public void function getMetaDataAfterMethodInvocation() {
        var o = setupTheTests();
        // Get uuid, and then get meta data, expecting this to be ok
        debug(o.getUUID());
        debug(GetMetaData(o));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this buggy behaviour in both CF 9.0.2 and 10.0.9.

I'd raise a bug if I was you.

The repro case can be simplified a lot from what you have:

```
// C.cfc
component {}

<!--- test.cfm --->
<cfscript>
o1 = new C();
writeDump(getMetaData(o1)); // OK

o2 = objectLoad(objectSave(o1));
writeDump(getMetadata(o2)); // breaks
</cfscript>
```

I don't know what to suggest by way of work-around, given it's so clearly and fundamentally broken.

Comment: Hmmm. Simply doing writeDump(o) before the getMetadata() call "fixes" it. It might be worth decompiling writeDump() and see what it's doing... it's obviously nudging the object in some way to cause the metadata to generate. It's still a bug though, and you should still raise it as such: https://bugbase.adobe.com/

Comment: Well thanks for the confirmation that I am not going crazy. Will look into submitting as bug asap :) also seemed that calling any method would cause it to be ok. Maybe cf only pulls in data following a method or writedump call

Comment: As mentioned in update above, have now raised the bug with adobe so hopefully it may get attention.  https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3546237

Comment: Have accepted this as an answer as nothing further seems forthcoming - I guess it's in Adobe's hands now.  That and the fact that this specific code may well end up on Railo which doesn't suffer this problem.